# How to stop sudo PAM messages in auth.log for a specific user?

Tags: sudo, logs, authentication, pam

I am using Zabbix for monitoring my environment and `zabbix_agentd` executes as user `zabbix` one custom script every 60 seconds; it uses `sudo` to run this script as `root`.

In `/var/log/auth.log` I see every 60 seconds:

```
Aug 11 17:40:32 my-server sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 11 17:40:32 my-server sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

I want to stop this message from flooding my log.  I added the following line to `/etc/pam.d/sudo` file, immediately before `session required pam_unix.so`:

```
session [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in sudo quiet uid = 0
```

and the message disappeared.

**But the problem** is that this way I have suppressed every PAM message when someone is executing a script with `sudo` as `root`.

I want to stop the message only for user `zabbix` (not all other users). `sudo` knows that `zabbix` user wants to execute the script with `root` privileges and is there any way to tell PAM that?  How can I tell PAM not to log for a specific user when using `sudo`?

**Note**: I tried filtering the messages in syslog; although this works, it has the same problem as the above, namely that it is too indiscriminate, as the log message does not indicate which user is becoming root.

Comment: It supports filtering and with filtering it works. I tried that but I do not like it, because filtering is not a universal way. One day some character in the message will change or something will change and my filter will fail. I am searching for a solution with configuration parameter, directive or something similar to be sure that this will be stopped in all cases. And the message says `session closed for user root` and if I filter it in fact I am filtering all messages. I want for a specific user who is not mentioned in the message and I cannot filter by its name...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You seem pretty close with your PAM conf line:

```
session [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in sudo quiet uid = 0
```

Looking at the manual page for `pam_succeed_if`, I think you want to test that the requesting user (**`ruser`**) is `zabbix`.

So I suggest:

```
session [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet uid = 0 ruser = zabbix
```

That will suppress the next test when user `zabbix` becomes `root` (but no other transitions).  I've tested this with a pair of my own users.

Remove the `uid = 0` test in the above if you want to keep quiet about `zabbix` becoming any user, rather than just root.

I removed the `service in sudo` test: it's redundant given that this line is in `/etc/pam.d/sudo`.

Comment: Thank you! That is what I am looking for. Perfect! And thanks for the suggestion to remove `service in sudo`.

Comment: If you also want to remove the `[user] : TTY=unknown ; PWD=... ; USER=root ; COMMAND=...` line from the log as well, you can add this to a sudoers.d/ file: `Defaults:[user] !logfile, !syslog` (replace `[user]` where appropriate)

Comment: @thom_nic What is the path to that file?

Comment: Any file under `/etc/sudoers.d/` - I prefer to use the name of the user, group or application to which this applies. See https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html

Comment: @thom_nic Could you please post this as an answer a bit more expanded? I don't see the format you propose above. In addition I don't think there is a `:` in there. And are the `logfiles` explicit or something that should be replaced?

Comment: @not2qubit [added info on sudo logging to my answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224370/how-to-stop-sudo-pam-messages-in-auth-log-for-a-specific-user/443221#443221)

Comment: This worked for me after changing `success=1` to `success=done`. `success=1` is nowhere to be found in `man pam.d`

Comment: @MarchH, those are completely different actions.  `success=1` skips only the next test (the `pam_unix.so` one), whereas `success=done` will skip _all_ the following tests.  On Debian, `man pam.d` says "_The action can take one of the following forms:_" ⋯ "_**`done`**: equivalent to `ok` with the side effect of terminating the module stack and PAM immediately returning to the application._" ⋯ "_**`N` (an unsigned integer)**: jump over the next `N` modules in the stack._".

Answer (score 9):

Based on Toby's answer, I found a way to configure this in a slightly different way on Debian/Ubuntu.  For context, see:

- https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/libpam-runtime/pam-auth-update.8.en.html
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PAMConfigFrameworkSpec

So Debian/Ubuntu have this `pam-auth-update` command and when you look at `/etc/pam.d/sudo` it looks like this:

```
#%PAM-1.0

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

and `/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive` looks like this:

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive - session-related modules
# common to all non-interactive services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of modules that define tasks to be performed
# at the start and end of all non-interactive sessions.
#
# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
session [default=1]         pam_permit.so
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
session requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
session required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
session required    pam_unix.so
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

So sure, I could edit either of the above files but clearly there's some "higher power" at work here.  How to get my changes to play nice with other packages that might want to add pam rules?  To top it off, it seemed I couldn't just add a line in `/etc/pam.d/sudo` in between the two `@include`s like this..

```
##### THIS DIDN'T WORK :( ######
@include common-auth
@include common-account
session [default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet_success service = sudo uid = 0 ruser = myappuser
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

After reading the above links as well as other examples (see `/usr/share/pam-configs/unix`) I came up with this, in `/usr/share/pam-configs/myapp`:

```
# Don't log "session opened" messages for myapp user
# See: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PAMConfigFrameworkSpec
#      https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/libpam-modules/pam_succeed_if.8.en.html
Name: myapp disable session logging
Default: yes
Priority: 300
Session-Type: Additional
Session:
    [default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet_success service = sudo uid = 0 ruser = myappuser
```

`Session` and `Session-Type` control which files are edited and `Priority` defines what order they go in.  After adding that file and running `pam-auth-update`, `/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive` looks like this (at the bottom:)

```
#... omitted
session required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
session [default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet_success service = sudo uid = 0 ruser = myappuser
session required pam_unix.so 
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

... which is what we want because our `pam_succeed_if` line needs to come before `session required pam_unix.so`.  (That line comes from  `/use/share/pam-configs/unix` and has a `Priority: 256` so it ends up second.)  Note also that I left the `service = sudo` predicate since `common-session-noninteractive` might also be included in other configs besides `sudo`.

In my case, I had already packaged my code as a .deb installer so I added the `/usr/share/pam-configs/myapp` file, and added `pam-auth-update --package` to my `postinst` and `prerm` scripts and I'm good to go!

#### Caveat...

If you read the [PAMConfigFrameworkSpec article that I linked above](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PAMConfigFrameworkSpec), it defines a `Session-Interactive-Only` option, but does **not have a way to specify only noninteractive rules**.  So `/etc/pam.d/common-session` was **also updated**.  I don't think there's a way around this. If you're ok with interactive sessions not being logged for that user (it IS a service account, right?) then you should be all set!

#### Bonus: how to also remove sudo log output

In addition to the `session openened|closed` lines that PAM emits, `sudo` logs additional information about the command that's run.  It looks like this:

```
[user] : TTY=unknown ; PWD=... ; USER=root ; COMMAND=...
```

If you *also* want to remove that, open this link then continue below...

- https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html#Authentication_and_logging

So... you're probably familiar with typical `/etc/sudoers.d/___` setup which might do something like this for a service account which needs superuser privs for a some actions:

```
myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/ping
```

that might go in `/etc/sudoers.d/10_myuser`.  Well, among other things [you can also specify `Defaults`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html#Defaults).  Note specifically this syntax `'Defaults' ':' User_List`

Now, look at [the SUDOERS OPTIONS section](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html#SUDOERS_OPTIONS).  Interesting bits include `log_input`, `log_output` but (probably) more importantly, `syslog` and `logfile`.  It appears to me that in recent versions of Debian, either rsyslog or `sudo` log to `stdout` or `stderr` by default.  So for me this was showing up in the journald log for my service, and not e.g. `/var/log/auth.log` where it wouldn't get mixed into my application logs.  To remove the sudo logging, I added the following to `/etc/sudoers.d/10_myuser` so it looks like:

```
Defaults:myuser !logfile, !syslog
myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/ping
```

YMMV, if you feel disabling logging creates issues with security audits you might also try to solve this via rsyslog filters.

Comment: The way you implemented the "session opened/closed" stuff didn't work for me. There are two reasons: 
(1) You didn't specify to use `success=1`, (which skips the next clause), and (2) Because how you specified `service = sudo`, any running CRON jobs, results in `requirement "service = sudo" not met by user "root"`. (And possibly other side effects.) However, your *Bonus* stuff worked great! Thank you.

Comment: How does your `postinst` and `prerm` scripts look?

Comment: @not2qubit re: `success=1` - I'd rather not skip `pam_unix` altogether.  I only want to stop logging the output which `[default=ignore]` seems to achieve just fine without skipping pam_unix.

Comment: re: `cron` jobs and `service = sudo`:  Is it possible that your cron jobs are running as an unpriv user, but you're not calling `sudo` as part of the cron jobs?

Comment: You  probably want `!log_allowed` instead of the broader that `!syslog` that hides security incidents.

Answer (score 4):

After quite a bit of scary testing and research, I have found a working solution for the Debian Stretch (on Raspberry). There are surely more than one way to accomplish what OP ask for. But the PAM documentation is overwhelming, so most stuff is really TL;DR.

1. You can add a custom string filter for *rsyslog*  in: `/etc/rsyslog.d/anyname.conf` by using:
   **`:msg, contains, "session opened for user root by pi"       stop`**
2. You can directly edit `/etc/pam.d/sudo`
3. You can do it the right way by creating a custom PAM config file in: `/usr/share/pam-configs/`
4. You can do some by creating a custom *sudoers* file in: `/etc/sudoers.d/020_pi`

I'll show you how to do (2) and (4).

> **WARNING**
>
> Do not edit any files in `/etc/pam.d/` without first changing their world write permissions. If you do not, and make a mistake, you can get locked out of any future use of **sudo/su**! So make sure you have tested the new settings before you change it back. (Default is **644**)

---

#### To get rid of "session open/close":

We want to get rid of the following `/var/log/auth.log` spam:

```
May 10 11:28:03 xxx sudo[26437]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 10 11:28:07 xxx sudo[26437]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Do this:

```bsh
# sudo chmod 666 /etc/pam.d/sudo
# sudo cat /etc/pam.d/sudo

#%PAM-1.0

@include common-auth
@include common-account
session [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet_success uid = 0 ruser = pi
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

What is of crucial importance here, is that `success=1`, means to skip the next 1 clause (or in PAM lingo "jump over the next module in the stack"), if successful.

From `man pam.conf`:

> **ignore**  - when used with a stack of modules, the module's return
>   status will not contribute to the return code the application obtains.
>
> **done**    - equivalent to ok with the side effect of terminating the
>   module stack and PAM immediately returning to the application.
>
> **N**    - equivalent to ok with the side effect of jumping over the next N modules in the stack.

Next, reboot and let it run a few hours (to check cron jobs for example) to test that this works. Then make sure to re-instate the file permissions, otherwise you'll have a gaping security hole in your system. (`sudo chmod 644 /etc/pam.d/sudo`)

---

#### To get rid of repeated "TTY PWD COMMAND" messages:

We also want to get rid of messages like this:

```
May 11 18:23:20 xxx sudo:       pi : TTY=unknown ; PWD=... ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/arp-scan -q -l
```

In my case, this was generated by an IDS script that was running *arp-scan* every few minutes. To remove it from showing up in the logs, create the following file:

```bsh
# sudo nano /etc/sudoers.d/020_pi
# sudo cat /etc/sudoers.d/020_pi

Defaults:pi     !logfile, !syslog
pi xxx = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/arp-scan
```

(Here `xxx` is your machine name, and `pi` is the username.)

Comment: > Do not edit any files in /etc/pam.d/ without first changing their world write permissions....  

Highly suggest running another terminal session as root instead e.g. `sudo su -`  Then you don't have to set dangerous permissions and risk forgetting to change it back.

Comment: @thom_nic Have you tested this? My guess is that if you accidentally block sudo/su usage in PAM, then no matter what you do, will produce an error, even in a root shell. If it is not, then PAM is probably not working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Log in as root, edit the file `/etc/pam.d/sudo` and add

```
session [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet uid = 0 ruser = alice
```

where `alice` is your username. This will prevent session open and close logs.

To prevent logging of commands, edit `/etc/sudoers` and add

```
Defaults:alice     !logfile, !syslog
```

just above this line `alice ALL:(ALL) :ALL`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it seems you just duplicated the already existing answers

Comment: Should I remove it?

Answer (score -2):

You will get:

```
pam_succeed_if(sudo:session): unknown attribute "ruser"
```

with your answer.

```
#%PAM-1.0

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in zabbix quiet use_uid
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
```

works but you will still get a :

```
pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

in your logs.

Comment: Please specify: 1. what file you are editing, 2. who is "you" and what it solves.