# Filter logs with journald

Tags: systemd-journald

A monitoring service that executes every minute requires `sudo`. With this my logs are full of `pam_unix` entries, telling me that this service logged in with `sudo`.

Now that I have `journald` on this machine, I thought maybe I could filter those logs, so that `journald` simply ignores them (by regex matching/other parameters).

I don't want to filter the output (I could do that with `journalctl`), I don't want those entries to be stored.

Is this possible with `journald`?

Comment: Nothing in the journald-related manpages indicates this is possible. You could tell journald to forward everything to rsyslog and get rsyslog to do the filtering, but I suppose this is not what you want.

Comment: @muru I checked the `rsyslog` docs and it has a filtering concept, but for filtering to different files. I couldn't find anything in the `rsyslog` docs to indicate that it could be used for discarding the messages, but setting the file to `/dev/null` might work.

Comment: @jordanm you don't have to send it to a file in `rsyslog`. There is a discard action: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/actions.html?highlight=tilde#discard

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but really? There is no way to do this with journald? I thought journald is so great, there must be an option for filtering logs when they come in.

Comment: [This SO question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224370/how-to-stop-sudo-pam-messages-in-auth-log-for-a-specific-user) does not answer the journald filtering, but it does address the `sudo` / `pam_unix` messages: