# How to omit PAM log messages for specific user (pam_succeed_if quiet)

Tags: sudo, logs, pam, syslog, systemd-journald

I'm using a monitoring agent (`telegraf`) to monitor fail2ban. Unfortunately, it requires SuperUser rights to execute `fail2ban-client`, which causes 24 system log messages every 10 seconds... Do the math, my system log is absolutely cluttered.

I'd like to suppress these messages in my system log, if possible only caused by telegraf:

```
sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

I've tried using a custom "rule" in `/etc/pam.d/sudo` to suppress those messages, without success:

```
# cat /etc/pam.d/sudo
#%PAM-1.0

session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0
@include common-auth
@include common-account
session [default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet uid = 0 user = root ruser = telegraf
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

Only the line starting with `session` was added in that file. The solution was adapted from [How to stop sudo PAM messages in auth.log for a specific user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/443367/33036)

However, the log messages still appear in `/var/log/auth.log` as well as `journalctl -xe`

I've tried `quiet_success` as well as `quiet` flags (found in `man pam_succeed_if`). Also using `success=1` makes `telegraf` fail to execute `fail2ban-client`, I'd guess because it needs an interactive tty?

This is logged using the `debug` flag:

```
Sep 20 11:34:51 host sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep 20 11:34:51 host sudo: pam_succeed_if(sudo:session): 'uid' resolves to '0'
Sep 20 11:34:51 host sudo: pam_succeed_if(sudo:session): 'user' resolves to 'root'
Sep 20 11:34:51 host sudo: pam_succeed_if(sudo:session): 'ruser' resolves to 'telegraf'
Sep 20 11:34:51 host sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

As far as I can tell, the "rule" matches uid, user and ruser correctly, but does not suppress log messages. Am I missing a reboot, or what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working with the following configuration (`/etc/pam.d/sudo`)

```
#%PAM-1.0

session [success=done default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet uid = 0 user = root ruser = telegraf
session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

To be honest, I don't know what the problem was, but I figured maybe the order is important. Please use this information at your own risk, I have no idea what I'm doing... But my syslog looks a lot cleaner now :)

(Somebody explaining the situation would still be greatly appreciated)

Comment: I realize this is old but, do I need to restart anything to get this to start working/stop logging?