# How to stop PAM messages in auth.log for a specific script run with sudo?

Tags: linux, shell-script, sudo, pam, syslog

I've set up a bash script to run automatically (from crontab) with `sudo` privileges using [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/155827) `visudo` solution.

Since the script requires multiple runs, it pollutes my `/var/log/auth.log`, so I disabled the `TTY` output (**only for the specific script I designated in `visudo`**) by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14278264/11750716) solution successfully. By `TTY`, I mean this kind of log entry: `[user] : TTY=unknown ; PWD=... ; USER=root ; COMMAND=...`.

But I'm left with the following 2 lines in `/var/log/auth.log` **each** time the script is run (it being run with `sudo` privileges). Since it runs many times, I have this output many many times, which is annoying:

```
Nov 01 00:00:00 1234567 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 01 00:00:00 1234567 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

I'm aware of this question: [How to stop sudo PAM messages in auth.log for a specific user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224370/how-to-stop-sudo-pam-messages-in-auth-log-for-a-specific-user), which seems to allow the disabling of PAM messages *per user*.

But I couldn't find a solution to disable the above PAM message in `/var/log/auth.log` **for a specific script only**. Basically I'm looking for the equivalent of what I did for the `TTY` output with `visudo`, which carves-out from logging *only*  the specific script I've designated.

Any ideas?

(The system is running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Comment: How are you running this script? From crontab?

Comment: yes the script is launched by crontab (I've updated question to specify this)

Answer (score 1):

If the script is being run from `crontab` one option would be to run it from root's `crontab` (or the system one) so that `sudo` is no longer required.

Comment: The reason I didn't include it in root's `crontab` is that the script is actually a Python script itself running some bash scripts (the bash scripts being the ones that require the `sudo` privilege and that leave traces in logs). The requirement is that I use the Python installation (with related binary and installed packages) that is available for the user that is `sudo`ing, and would not want to mirror the Python installation package for `root` user.

Comment: Could it be a system-wide installation of Python?

Comment: I just tested and it works, thank you. Python is installed in an environment with the Anaconda distribution (itself installed for `user`, not for `root`), so the binary is located in `/home/[USER_NAME]/anaconda3/envs/[ENV_NAME]/bin/python`. I did `sudo su` and ran the Python script (`./python_script.py`) as `root`. The script has a header pointing to the Python binary `#!/usr/bin/env /home/[USER_NAME]/anaconda3/envs/[ENV_NAME]/bin/python`. This seems to work correctly, the Python packages remain available even if script is run as `root`. Is this behavior normal / expected?

Comment: If you run programs underneath an ordinary user's account as root, you've just thrown all your root security away. (The non-privileged user can change or replace the application you're running as root to get root access.) If you're doing that you really would be better off installing whatever tools it is as part of a system-wide installation.

Comment: Ohh thank you for pointing that out. Going on this path, I've found a [guide](https://medium.com/@pjptech/installing-anaconda-for-multiple-users-650b2a6666c6) to install Anaconda system-wide, which seems to account for the point you raised (*Remove write permission for ‘group’ and ‘others’*). I'll consider this path as it would require me to re-install the Anaconda package and environments, and use a common environment. In the meantime if a solution for PAM messages is feasible, I'd be grateful.